# How to write a simple input validation for this code

Tags: java

I need a help on writing a user input validation programm. I have been given a homework to write a Java program, using an array or an ArrayList, to store 10 messages in it and ask the user to choose between 0 and 10, to display a message and also to generate another random message.

I was able to complete this program and submit it, but my program crashes if the user puts any other character than Integer, or if he puts an Integer,v that is not within the range of 0 to 10.

I want to resubmit this homework with input validation for a better grade so i decided to ask help from the pros, once again i just started learning programming about 5 weeks ago.

Below is the homework i submitted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Please read through the folowing 10 messages and follow the instruction under them.");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList <String>(10); // making object in ArrayList

       //create an ArrayList object

     //Add elements to Arraylist

    list.add(0, "I try to be good."); 
     list.add(1, "Nobody is Perfect."); 
     list.add(2, "Life is good"); 
     list.add(3, "This is me.");
     list.add(4, "System out"); 
     list.add(5, "It's summer time"); 
     list.add(6, "i like green pepper,"); 
     list.add(7, "He is funny");
     list.add(8, "There are Challenges"); 
     list.add(9, "What is your name");

     shoutOutCannedMessage(list);

     System.out.println("Retrieving stored messages from Arraylist");

   ShoutOutRandomMessage();

     }


      //This method retrieves values from ArrayList using get method


    public static void shoutOutCannedMessage(List<String> message) {

   int size = message.size();
     for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
     {
System.out.println(message.get(i));

     }
    // To retrieve User's Choice   
     int userChoice;
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     // Inform the user to select one of the messages that poped up above
     System.out.println("Please enter a number of your choice from 0 to 10");
     userChoice = scanner.nextInt();
     System.out.println(message.get(userChoice));
    }
/**
 *
 */
public static void ShoutOutRandomMessage() {



  //holds the words to be generated.

  String[] subject= {" He", " me", " She", "We"};
  String[] verb= {" do", " say", " get", " make", " know"};
  String[] adjective= {" good", " new", " first", " last", " long"};
  String[] object= {" cup", " map", " house", " computer"};
  String[] adverb= {" up. ", " so. ", " out. ", " now. ", " just"};


   Random r = new Random(); //intialize a Random
   int selectedElement = r.nextInt(subject.length);

  //randomly create sentence.



 {

 String randomSentence=subject[selectedElement] 
  + verb[selectedElement]       
  + adjective[selectedElement] 
  + object[selectedElement]
  + adverb[selectedElement];

 System.out.println("ShoutOut: " + randomSentence );

  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number you get from user is stored in variable `userChoice`. You need to check if this number is valid. You can do this simply by adding `if`.

Replace this code:

```
 System.out.println("Please enter a number of your choice from 0 to 10");
 userChoice = scanner.nextInt();
 System.out.println(message.get(userChoice));
```

with this:

```
 System.out.println("Please enter a number of your choice from 0 to 10");
 userChoice = scanner.nextInt();
 if(userChoice >=0 && userChoice <=10)
     System.out.println(message.get(userChoice));
 else
     System.out.println("The number you entered is not valid.");
```

You can go a step further and check if the user entered a valid number. This can be done by:

```
 System.out.println("Please enter a number of your choice from 0 to 10");
 String userChoiceStr = scanner.next();
 try{
     userChoice = Integer.parseInt(userChoiceStr);
     if(userChoice >=0 && userChoice <=10)
         System.out.println(message.get(userChoice));
     else
         System.out.println("The number you entered is not valid.");
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("The number you entered is not valid.");
 }
```

To let user try again if he entered wrong input:
You want the process to repeat if he enters wrong input. Repeating processes means loops. there are many constructs in Java to write loops. In this case the best choice would be to use `do-while` loop as you want the user to try at least once.

```
boolean isInputValid = false;
do{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number of your choice from 0 to 10");
    String userChoiceStr = scanner.next();
    try{
        userChoice = Integer.parseInt(userChoiceStr);
        if(userChoice >=0 && userChoice <=10) {
            System.out.println(message.get(userChoice));
            isInputValid = true;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("The number you entered is not valid.");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       System.out.println("The number you entered is not valid.");
    }
} while (!isInputValid);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply Balkrishna, i used the 2nd example you provided which solved the problem of crashing when user input like a string instead of integer but the only one probem i am facing now is that i dont know how to make the program allow the user to try again untill the correct input is received .Thank you once again.

Comment: See updated answer. Hope the code is clear to you. Control flow constructs like if-else, switch-case, for, while, do-while are used very frequently in Java programs and it is important that you understand them very well.

Comment: I am very grateful for this, and i must say you are better than my teacher with the way you explain things, i really wish you are my teacher lol...I will keep on reading all tutorials in this thread because i really want to becomer a programmer, not just to pass this class.For many years i have always want to be into Programming, i believe now is the time. I will try to brush myself up in Java and then move to Python, hopefully one day i can also start helping out. I really cant thank you enough.

Comment: you are welcome. I wish you good luck. For now you can accept the answer if this answer helped you (by clicking on the check symbol on the left side).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void AlphaOnly(String input,JLabel obj){
if(!"".equals(input)){
    obj.setText(" ");
    warning=false;

    char c[] = input.toCharArray();

    int count = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<c.length; x++){
        if(!Character.isAlphabetic(c[x])){// && c[x]!='-' && c[x]!='(' && c[x]!=')' && c[x]!='+'&& c[x]!='/'&& c[x]!='\\'){
            count=+1;

        }
    }
    if(count>0){
        obj.setText("*Please use valid characters.");
        warning=true;
    }else{
        obj.setText(" ");
        warning=false;
    }
}else{
    obj.setText("*This Field cannot be left Empty.");
    warning=true;
}   
}
public void DigitOnly(String input,JLabel obj){
char c[] = input.toCharArray();
if(!"".equals(input)){
    obj.setText(" ");
    warning=false;


        int count = 0;
        for(int x=0; x<c.length; x++){
            if(!Character.isDigit(c[x])){// && c[x]!='-' && c[x]!='(' && c[x]!=')' && c[x]!='+'&& c[x]!='/'&& c[x]!='\\'){
            count=+1;

            }
        }

            if(count>0){
                obj.setText("*Please use valid characters.");
                warning=true;
            }else{
                obj.setText(" ");
                warning=false;
                if(c.length<=4){
                    obj.setText(" ");
                    warning=false;
                }else{
                    obj.setText("*Four digits Only.");
                    warning=true;
                }
            }

}else{
    obj.setText("*This Field cannot be left Empty.");
    warning=true;
}    
}    
private void contactNumberCharOnly(String input,JLabel obj){
char c[] = input.toCharArray();
if(!"".equals(input)){
    if((c.length>=7)&&(c.length<=14)){
        obj.setText(" ");
        warning=false;

        int count = 0;
        for(int x=0; x<c.length; x++){
            if(!Character.isDigit(c[x]) && c[x]!='-' && c[x]!='(' && c[x]!=')' && c[x]!='+'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>0){
            obj.setText("*Please use valid characters.");
            warning=true;
        }else{
            obj.setText(" ");
            warning=false;
        }
    }else{
        obj.setText("*This is not a valid contact no.");
        warning=true;
    }
}else{
    obj.setText("*This Field cannot be left Empty.");
    warning=true;
} 
}    
private void isValidEmail(String input,JLabel obj){

    if(!"".equals(input)){
        obj.setText(" ");
        warning=false;
        if(input.length()>13){
            if((!input.contains("@"))||(!input.endsWith(".com"))||(input.contains(" "))||(input.contains("/"))||(input.contains("\\"))||(input.contains("+"))||(input.contains("="))){
                obj.setText("*Please use a valid Email Address.");
                warning=true;
            }else{
                obj.setText(" ");
                warning=false;
            }
        }else{
            obj.setText("*Please use a valid Email Address.");
            warning=true;
        }
    }else{
        obj.setText("*This Field cannot be left Empty.");
        warning=true;
    } 
}
public void AlphaNumericOnly(String input,JLabel obj){
if(!"".equals(input)){
    obj.setText(" ");
    warning=false;

    char c[] = input.toCharArray();

    int count = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<c.length; x++){
        if((!Character.isAlphabetic(c[x]))&&(!Character.isDigit(c[x]))){// && c[x]!='-' && c[x]!='(' && c[x]!=')' && c[x]!='+'&& c[x]!='/'&& c[x]!='\\'){
            count=+1;

        }
    }
    if(count>0){
        obj.setText("*Please use valid characters.");
        warning=true;
    }else{
        obj.setText(" ");
        warning=false;
    }
}else{
    obj.setText("*This Field cannot be left Empty.");
    warning=true;
}   
}
```

I've written These simple codes to check "input" on a project I made.
These checks user input if they are:
1. Letters only
2. numbers only
3.Valid Email (although this only checks if user input has '@' & '.com')
4. Valid contact number (checks only if there is 7 numbers or more)
5. Alphanumeric Only- has no special characters

When the user inputs an 'invalid' character on a textbox, a red label appears that warns the user of invalid input.

These are only simple solutions and there are better ways to solve this problem